# Using for with options works only for some cases

Tags: scala

If I write this:

```
val (x, y) = (Some(8), None)
def f(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y

for {x0 <- x; y0 <- y} yield f(x0, y0)
```

I receive the expected result: `res5: Option[Int] = None`

But if I try to write:

```
for {x0 <- x; y0 <- y} yield (x0 + y0)
```

I receive the next error:

```
<console>:10: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method + in class Int of type (x: Char)Int
and  method + in class Int of type (x: Byte)Int
match argument types (Nothing)
          for {x0 <- x; y0 <- y} yield (x0 + y0)
```

Can anybody explain me why my last try doesn't work? I'm probably missing something in the internals of how for and Options work. x0 should be `Int`, shouldn't it?

Comment: In the first case, you explicitly specify the types which your function expects. In the second case, you leave it to the compiler and it's getting confused.

Comment: Anyway I can rewrite it without external function use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pasting this into the REPL will make it clear that `y` is not `Option[Int]`:

```
scala> val (x, y) = (Some(8), None)
x: Some[Int] = Some(8)
y: None.type = None
```

The compiler cannot in any way infer `None` as `Option[T]` without explicitly being told as much, so it's inferred as `None.type`. You should use an explicit type annotation:

```
scala> val (x, y) = (Some(8), Option.empty[Int])
x: Some[Int] = Some(8)
y: Option[Int] = None
```

`val (x, y): (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = (Some(8), None)` will also work.

Comment: The first option isn't an explicit type annotation; only the second one is.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already say how to fix the error; I'll expand a bit on why you exactly get the error.

`x0` is `Int`; `y0` is not (it's `Nothing`, since `None extends Option[Nothing]`). `Nothing` is subtype of every type, including all the types that can be added to `Int`, such as `Byte` and `Char` (as the message says). The compiler therefore doesn't know which `+` it should use. Even though it actually doesn't matter (all would result in `None`), this is still an error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the type of y is *not* Option[Int] (as you might be expecting) but None.

```
val (x, y) = (Some(8), Some(4))

for {x0 <- x; y0 <- y} yield (x0 + y0)
```

Works just fine. So in any real-world use-case (where x and y are Option[Int]) this will work fine. It's only because you have an explicit None that the compiler gets a bit confused.